# Debugging memory usage with dumps without Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, memory-leaks, visual-studio-debugging

This [old blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production/) describes how to diagnose memory issues using dump files. Unfortunately, the method described only works with Visual Studio Ultimate, which I don't have access to.

How could I extract similar information from a dump? Ideally, I'd like to know which objects are taking the most memory and where they are in the hierarchy of references. I don't really need to compare two dumps at this point.

I know how to use Diagnostic Tools window to get that information when debugging a live application, but I'm looking for a solution that works in a dump-only situation.

Comment: WinDBG can do it all, but you do have to learn some black magic: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paullou/2011/06/28/debugging-managed-code-memory-leak-with-memory-dump-using-windbg/

Comment: [use DebugDiag Analyzer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/analyze-a-memory-dump-using-the-debug-diagnostic-tool/) and analyze the memory usage from the dumps

Comment: I would recommend to get normal paid memory profiler which appreciates your time and shows you what you want in two clicks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use VS IDE, Windbg would be a better choice.

[How do I use a dump file to diagnose a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514401/how-do-i-use-a-dump-file-to-diagnose-a-memory-leak)

Of course, you could also think about using other tools, like PerfView or DebugDiag Analyzer:

[Analyzing memory dump to find leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522329/analyzing-memory-dump-to-find-leak)